# Why is Romanian not a control language for Interlingua?

Tags: history, inspiration, eurocentrism, interlingua

IALA Interlingua is a naturalistic romance-based conlang. There are six *control languages* (primary: English, French, Italian, and Spanish/Portuguese  counted as one language "Iberian"; secondary: German and Russian) to determine the vocabulary of Interlingua. Romanian is not a control language.

Are there any statements (e.g., by the IALA or by Alexander Gode) why Romanian is not a control language of Interlingua?

Comment: I cannot find any statements by Gode or the IALA, but given that Interlingua is very VERY predominantly Western Romance, it seems likely Romanian was excluded due to the amount of influence the [Balkan Sprachbund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balkan_sprachbund) has had on it.

Comment: You cant choose every language so he chose some and left out others.